# Pairing devices doesn't showing QR code in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-wifi-debugging

I'm trying to make pairing with my physical device for wifi debugging but it is showing this message but I have already downloaded the latest `platform-tools`. How to enable it? My OS is **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**.
[image]

In my SDK manager-
[image]